# Need help to compute running time

Tags: matlab

I have made following matlab code for computing cpu time of
matlab inbuilt function pinv(A) to compute the Pseudo inverse of a given matrix.
I had runed the matlab code 1000 times &  calculated the mean of the results.

Matlab code

```
A = rand(10) % given randomly generated matrix of order 10
REPS = 1000; % taking thousand times repetitions 

minTime = Inf; 

tic
for i=1:REPS
    tstart = tic;  

    x1=pinv(A)

    telapsed = toc(tstart);

    minTime = min(telapsed,minTime);
end

execTime = toc; % total execution time

averageTime = execTime/REPS
```

I am not sure whether my program is correct or not? I have to use these results for my project work. Could anybody help me with this. I would be very much thankful to you.

Comment: averagetime should be the average time of each iteration. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I edited your code. I changed it slightly. `execTime` is the total execution time. `averageTime` is the average time to calculate the pseudoinverse. `minTime` is the minimum time for one iteration.

You are also likely to get more accurate results if each iteration takes longer (See [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/understanding-wall-time-jitter-in-matlab-computations) for issues when the execution time is too short). The easiest way to do this is to increase the size of `A`, such as `A=rand(100)`. Depending on your machine, this still may not be large enough.

Comment: @Daryl Thanks a lot for helping me. I wanted to know whether my code is correct or not? Thanks again..:)

Comment: The edited code will work as you desire. As I said, you may not experience accurate results for the timing with `A` so small in size. As I suggested above, make the coefficient matrix `A` larger, so that the total execution time is longer for each iteration. (I will post these comments as an answer.)

Comment: @Daryl: Don't you want `A = rand(10)` to be inside the loop? This way you'll just get the average time it takes to invert one particular random matrix; if you want to average over different random matrices, you need to put the line that generates the random matrices inside the loop.

Comment: @joriki You will then incur additional execution time for the generation of new random matrices, in the outer tic/toc counter. The particular inverse is not important here, just the execution time to calculate one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from above comments)
I edited your code. I changed it slightly. `execTime` is the total execution time. `averageTime` is the average time to calculate the pseudoinverse. `minTime` is the minimum time for one iteration. You are also likely to get more accurate results if each iteration takes longer (See [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/understanding-wall-time-jitter-in-matlab-computations) for issues when the execution time is too short). The easiest way to do this is to increase the size of `A`, such as `A=rand(100)`. Depending on your machine, this still may not be large enough.

The edited code will work as you desire. As I said, you may not experience accurate results for the timing with `A` so small in size. As I suggested above, make the coefficient matrix `A` larger, so that the total execution time is longer for each iteration. (I will post these comments as an answer.)

Comment: Ya took larger order random generated matrix.

Comment: Yes. I did that so that in the `pinv(..)` function didn't execute too quickly. I'm not sure about your machine, but with `A=rand(10)`, (my version of) `pinv(..)` was executing too quickly for tic and toc to accurately register elapsed times. Changing `A` to be larger resolved this problem, at the expense of using more memory. This may not be a problem on you machine, I am unsure.

Comment: Ya i did for larger order matrices. For smaller order matrices it is taking very less time.